# whitespace in php code causing html to move on page

Tags: php, pagination

My pagination script is server side and requires that the html is written in the php. When you click on the certain buttons the whole line shifts to the right and/or left a character space or two. I've been looking at this for over an hour and about to put a gun in my mouth, going through it character space by character space and I'm pretty certain it has to do with whitespacing.

I'm not expecting anyone here to look through it for the space but I was wondering if someone has dealt with this and could recommend where to look for the whitespace that could be moving my line and/or if there was anything out there that could just remove all white space without affecting the integrity of the code.

```
    $prevlink = ($page > 1)?'<a href="?page=1" title="First page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page='.($page - 1).'"title="Previous page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>':'<span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span> <span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span>';

// The "forward" link 
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'"title="Next page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page='.$pages.'"title="Last page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>':'<span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span><span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span>';

 // The "back" link 
$prevlink = ($page > 1)?'<a href="?page=1" title="First page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page='.($page - 1).'"title="Previous page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>':'<span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span> <span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span>';

// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'"title="Next page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page='.$pages.'"title="Last page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>':'<span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span><span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span>';

// Display the paging information
    echo '<div id="paging">',$prevlink,'<p>Listing',$page,'of',$pages,'</p>',$nextlink,'</div>';
```

Source:

page loaded:

```
<div id="paging"><span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span> <span class="disabled"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span><p>Listing1of31</p><a href="?page=2"title="Next page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page=31"title="Last page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a></div><div class="edit_listing" style="overflow:hidden;">
```

click once to next page causes the line to shift once to the right. here's the source after click:

```
<div id="paging"><a href="?page=1" title="First page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page=1"title="Previous page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><p>Listing2of31</p><a href="?page=3"title="Next page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a><a href="?page=31"title="Last page"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a></div><div class="edit_listing" style="overflow:hidden;">
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML and CSS?

Comment: @j08691 go ahead and post that as an answer :) of course the source code would show where the issue is

Comment: When it shifts by characters not on page load, but when you click it, that's a client-side issue. We need to see the code that the browser's interpreting, not the server.

Comment: since this is server side pagination though i think the buttons are going to a new page but it's a really good point. Ok will post

Comment: @Nerixel posted. i think it's at the very beginning since it's the entire line moving.

Comment: @Rhillz The first one is in a span where the second is not, does that span have any padding or margin that could add space?

Comment: bootstrap has a lot of modified disabled classes, i will look through these thank you very much @Nerixel

Comment: @Nerixel my css indents all <a> tags, just fixed it, i would never have thought to check the css, if you want to write it up below i'll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has a span where the second does not, it's very likely that CSS is being applied to that span or elements within it.